# How to add code in MainActivity.java file in android

Tags: java, android, react-native

Iam using a react native package, in docs i need to add that in MainActivity.java file,

```
import android.os.Bundle; // here
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
// react-native-splash-screen >= 0.3.1
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen; // here
// react-native-splash-screen < 0.3.1
import com.cboy.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen; // here

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SplashScreen.show(this);  // here
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    // ...other code
}
```

But my problem is my MainActivity.java file is diffrent, Here is my MainActivity.java file,

```
package myApp.tasawk.com;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */
  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "myApp";
  }
  @Override
  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
      @Override
      protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
       return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

I want to add those lines in my MainActivity.java, Where should I write my code, I want to add that part here,

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SplashScreen.show(this);  // here
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

but when I add it, the build faild

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have an older version of react native, but I think you can try this:

```
package myApp.tasawk.com;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */
  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "myApp";
  }
  @Override
  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
      @Override
      protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
       return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
      }
    };
  }
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SplashScreen.show(this);  // here
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe it is scrollable you just cant see the edge of the next card?